# How to close Visualforce page opened as Quick Action in Lightning through JavaScript?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, action, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

One of SObject Lightning pages contains an Action Button which opens a custom Visualforce page. How can I close it in other way than clicking the 'X' button?

So far I've tried:

`window.close()`, `window.top.close()`, `window.self.clse()`, `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();` and `window.top.location.href="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"` - none of these worked.

So far, an option closest to the solution was usage of `window.top.location.href="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"` but it refreshes the whole window.

I was hoping the `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();` line will do the trick, but I'm receiving `$A is nod defined` error, even if I use `<apex:useLightning/>` tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've eventually found a solution. The following script has to be included:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js'></script>`

Then use this line to close the Quick Action window:

`Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({ name: "publisher.close", payload:{ refresh: "true" }});`

Comment: Awesome!! Why is this so poorly documented!?

Comment: Well, looks kinda like a hack so I can understand why they didn't included it explicitly anywhere in the documentation.