# How to close dialog box in lightning experience using javascript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, quickaction

One of SObject Lightning pages contains an Action Button which opens a custom Visualforce page. I used javascript to open and close the dialog box. It works fine in classic but in lightning it won't close.
So far I've tried:

`window.close()`,

`window.top.close()`,

`window.self.close()`,

`$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();`

and 
`window.top.location.href="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"` - none of these worked.

So far, an option closest to the solution was usage of `window.top.location.href="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"` but it refreshes the whole window.

I was hoping the `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();` but it didn't work either.

Even i tried `Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({ name: "publisher.close", payload:{ refresh: "true" }});` too.

Comment: You are calling this method from Visualforce page and not lightning right?

Comment: Did you try the solution proposed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220675/how-to-close-visualforce-page-opened-as-quick-action-in-lightning-through-javasc) on a very similar question? Note that there's a script include line as well as the canvas call.

Comment: Yes, i am calling this method from vf page. But according to my knowledge i am using javascript may be thats why it doesn't support in lightning. Is it...? But i don't want to write whole new lightning component for this so, please me out if there's any other solution. Thanks.