# Unable to fire force:runActionComponent application event

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

Currently, LWC doesn't support QuickActionApi, but I really need it. Also, I am investigating option to wrap my LWC component by Aura component container, which will use quickActionApi and interact with nested LWC component. But, currently it is impossible for my Salesforce org, because it is impacted by the following issue [In Summer 19 lightning:quickActionAPI does not work when embedded in custom object in non-console app](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001PYcdQAG)

I want to fire from Chrome Developer Console standard application event **force:runActionComponent** (responsible for firing lightning quick actions from JS), but I am not able to do that. The same situation with external JS file loaded as static resource.

There are some events which can be fired in such way, for example:
*aura:applicationEvent, aura:componentEvent, aura:doneRendering, aura:doneWaiting, aura:locationChange force:closeQuickAction, force:createRecord, force:editRecord, force:navigateHome, etc.*

**Below the code I am trying to run in Chrome Developer Console**

```js
let leadConvertAction = window.top.$A.get("e.force:runActionComponent");
let params = {
    "descriptor": "force:quickActionRunnable",
    "attributes": {
        "quickActionDefinition": {
            "actionId": "Lead.Convert",
            "componentName": "forceChatter:lightningComponent",
            "publisherType": "LIGHTNING_COMPONENT",
            "attributes": {
                "contextualMessages": [],
                "publisherId": "...:...::Record:Desktop:...",
                "publisherFeedType": "Record",
                "quickActionLabel": "Convert",
                "quickActionApiName": "Lead.Convert"
            }
        },
        "subjectId": "...",
    },
    "isClientSideCreatable": true
};
leadConvertAction.setParams(params);
leadConvertAction.fire();
```

**UPDATE**

I have researched a little bit about this.

I've found out that descriptors of all events store in `app.js` .
It initializes events's definition in such way:

```js
$A.componentService.initEventDefs([{"descriptor":"markup: .... }, ...]);
```

There also is descriptor of `force:runActionComponent`.

Every descriptor has an attribute called `xs` which can have only 2 values: `I`('Inner' or something like that) or `G`(I suppose 'Global'), which is responsible for accessibility of the event.

`xs`-attribute of `force:runActionComponent` has value, which doesn't allow to fire this event from console or static resource JS-file.

I've tried to rerun `$A.componentService.initEventDefs` with modified values for `force:runActionComponent`, but it doesn't help. Even more - the same result if I replace 'xs' attributes for all event descriptors.

**Is it possible somehow to modify existing event descriptors?**

**Useful links**

1. [Firing Events from Non-Aura Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_external.htm)
2. [Lightning上に存在するAura Eventの参照 (Japanese)](https://qiita.com/mino0123/items/3e6c2a4348fd513fa175)
3. [AuraEventService.js on GitHub](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/f29e1a9/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/AuraEventService.js)
4. [How to close Visualforce page opened as Quick Action in Lightning through JavaScript?](https://qiita.com/mino0123/items/3e6c2a4348fd513fa175)
5. [How to close dialog box in lightning experience using javascript?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241196/how-to-close-dialog-box-in-lightning-experience-using-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)